# For Statement problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a `for` statement like

```
function myspecialFunction(elem) {

var currentItem = elem;
var currentImg = elem.find('img');

jQuery(currentImg).append('some text');
...
```

The problem seems to be that when `elem` has >1 of the same image item - it overwrites the data of the previous ? That is, when the same `currentImg` is returned - the statement overwrites the data of the previous ?

How can I ensure that same `currentImg` values are preserved ? i.e. I was hoping to use like `$(this)` but it doesn't appear to work ? My html looks like

Comment: What do you mean by "the previous"?

Comment: I mean that if I have 2 of the exact same html listed above - then the first iteration data is overwritten 2x because its same class and same img ? I want to preserve each ? The problem I am having is that - when the currentImg is overwritten - if another element exists with the same img and class then it writes over that too ?

Comment: Are you saying sometimes there are more than one image in the <a/> ?

Comment: Yes, i.e. if there are >2 of the same `<a>` - then as `i` increases, another set of text is appended too it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite the above as

```
jQuery('.class').each(function() {
    myspecialFunction(jQuery(this));
});

function myspecialFunction(elem) {  
    var currentItem = elem;
    var currentImg = elem.find('img');

//....
}
```

this is more idiomatic and [`$(selector).each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) introduces a closure to ensure that the correct value is captured in each loop iteration.

To do something similar with a plain for loop would be

```
var myClass = jQuery('.class');

for (var i = 0, len = myClass.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function () {
        myspecialFunction(jQuery(myClass[i]));
    })();
}

function myspecialFunction(elem) {

    var currentItem = elem;
    var currentImg = elem.find('img');
    // ...
}
```

Depending on your target browsers, being more specific than just a CSS class may help out too i.e. if all of the elements that you are selecting are all of the same tag name, then use the tag name in the selector.

Comment: -thanks for the response. my problem is that I have a large dataset and `$.each` doesn't perform that well.

Comment: Introduce a closure in the loop using an immediately invoked anonymous function.

Comment: how do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using jQuery `each` loop

```
jQuery('.class').each(function(){
    myspecialFunction($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

currentImg is local to the function it is in... not only will it be overwritten on each call, it won't even exist outside of that function.

Do you want to create a list of values that elem.find('img') returns?  If so then I think you are going about it wrong.  You need to scope a list variable outside of the function.

Comment: thanks for the response. any chance of some example code to assist :) The problem I am having is that - when the `currentImg` is overwritten - if the another element exists with the same `img` and `class` then it writes over that too ?

Comment: depends, you don't show the code where you use currentImg once you define it.

Comment: added some. basically, if there are >2 of the same `<a>` - then as `i` increases, another set of text is appended too it and so on.